# The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

The error is thrown when I try to navigate to the next screen. I have faced this before and adding a new context in the tree usually works. It didn't this time. What should I do?

```
Error:
E/flutter (22865): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] 
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null. 
E/flutter (22865): Receiver: null 
E/flutter (22865): Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType()
```

```
class _LoginMainState extends State<LoginMain> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Sorted.'),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff0A3D62),
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      colors: <Color>[
                    const Color(0xFF5761B2),
                    const Color(0xFF1FC588),
                  ])),
            ),
          ),
          drawer: null,
          body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              width: 360,
              height: 600,
              color: const Color(0xFF273748),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 400,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            colors: [Colors.white, Colors.grey[400]]),
                      ),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        child: Container(
                          child: MaterialButton(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            splashColor: Colors.teal,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              bool res = await AuthProvider().loginWithGoogle();
                              if (res) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => SortedMain()));
                              } else
                                print("Login failed");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because there is no context above your `MaterialApp`. The `Navigator` depends on the context of the `MaterialApp`, and since the only context available is above the app, it throws an error.

You mentioned that you've faced this issue before, and that you fixed it by adding an additional context. But you didn't specify **where** you added it.

To fix it, simply wrap the content under your MaterialApp with a `Builder`, or move it to a separate stateless or stateful widget.

```
class _LoginMainState extends State<LoginMain> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Added this
      home: Builder(
      builder: (context) => SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Sorted.'),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff0A3D62),
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      colors: <Color>[
                    const Color(0xFF5761B2),
                    const Color(0xFF1FC588),
                  ])),
            ),
          ),
          drawer: null,
          body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              width: 360,
              height: 600,
              color: const Color(0xFF273748),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 400,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            colors: [Colors.white, Colors.grey[400]]),
                      ),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        child: Container(
                          child: MaterialButton(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            splashColor: Colors.teal,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              bool res = await AuthProvider().loginWithGoogle();
                              if (res) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => SortedMain()));
                              } else
                                print("Login failed");
```

And if that doesn't work, just move the page into a different widget (Stateless or Stateful).